# How can I create an Empty Map and set the default value

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

I wanna create an empty map in java and then the default value to 0. Please let me know if below code is correct.

Actually, I'm having a python code which I'm trying to convert into Java. For the sake of understanding I'm pasting Python code here

Java Code:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11

```
import random

howMany = random.randint(0,1000)
stats = {} // EMPTY DICTIONARY
for i in range(howMany):
   value = random.randint(0,500)
   stats.setdefault(value,0)  // Setting the default value to 0 here
   stats[value]+=1
for item in stats:
   if stats[item] > 1:
       print item
```

In case of java if I do like this:

```
Java Code:


Map<String, Date> s = Collections.emptyMap();
```

Then I'll have to mention String and Date in the diamond. How can I do for Empty Map?

Here is the Java code I have written so far:

```
import java.util.Random;


public class PythonToJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Random rm = new Random();

        int i = rm.nextInt(1000);

        System.out.println("Random Number Generated is: " + i);
        for (int j = 0; j<i; j++){        
            int value = rm.nextInt(500);
        System.out.println("The value of VALUE is " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Please clarify.

Thanks !

Comment: Why downvote? Let me know the reason. Isn't my question good?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: Why dont you try to test the code and see if it works first? Then post your errors/exeptions...

Comment: @BrianRoach I know there are lot of documentations available but if you could explain a bit more then that would be great !

Comment: If you create a Map like this: Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); then all Integers will be 0.

Comment: @Aaron You could perhaps post this as an answer before someone other does...

Comment: Note that built-in Map implementations in Java do not have a concept of a "default value" as a Python dict does.

Comment: The code you've written so far doesn't even mention maps, and it's not clear what the random part has to do with anything else...

Comment: @mattb, Python dicts don't have a default value (but `collections.defaultdict` have).  This example here just facilitates setting a value into the dict in case there isn't sth set for this key yet.  That's not a property of the dict but of the code using the dict.

Comment: @Alfe you are right, I was thinking of operations on dicts like `get(key[, default])` and `setdefault(key[, default])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments Java did not have a Default Map like some other languages have. However the [apache commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) project has a [DefaultedMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/DefaultedMap.html) which returns a default value when the key is not part of the map. If you do not want to use a third party lib then you need to check on your own if a value for this key already exist and when not create it with the value zero.

Comment: Why would add a giant dependency to accomplish: `map.contains(key) ? map.get(key) : defaultValue;` ?